# Hyperlinks is not working in SharePoint 2013 Excel web access web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013

can you give me a clue on this? I used the "Excel web access web part" to display a named item from an excel file. everything looks good but the links in the excel file become inactive string. I did the same in another SharePoint 2013 site collection and it did work. 
 Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the  reason is that the file path is too long, and the address was shortened in excel but somehow it is not working when it is rendering in browsers. is there an option to shorten a long URL?for example, a long one as below?

https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/gblproc/resins/Shared%20Documents/Forms/All%20docs.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fgblproc%2Fresins%2FShared%20Documents%2FPrice%2FIndex%20tracking%2FIndex%20Reports&FolderCTID=0x012000C792F68BE58A7D4F85747D57A0495B3A&View=%257ddd